# Extending Angular resource causes GET request to fail in some scenarios

Tags: angularjs

We have a resource defined as follows:

```
var services = angular.module('services', ['ngResource']);  
services.factory('Facility', function ($resource) {
var resource = $resource('/facility/:id.json', {id: '@id'}, update);
    resource.restore = function (pathParams, success, error) {
        $resource('/facility/:id/restore.json', {}, update).update(pathParams, {}, success, error);
    };
    return resource;
});
```

where update is defined as a custom action, because Angular does not support PUT by default, as follows:

```
var update = {update: {method: 'PUT'}};
```

Now the GET url fired by call to Facility.get is `http://localhost:9091/facilities/1.json` for e.g., which works normally. But we have Spring security in use and after a session timeout and subsequent redirect to login and login successful, we do a location.reload(), which reloads the edit page, but this GET url fails with JSON parse error "No content to map ... end of input". We have found that redefining another service factory like

```
services.factory('FacilityGet', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('facilities/:id', {}, {});
}
```

and using it solves the problem. Using either of the update action or the "{id: '@id'}" params causes problems - only when we exclude both of them, the corresponding resource fires the correct GET request.

Please note that the GET fired from earlier resource failed only the very first time after login redirection, but worked fine later. Any help or pointers will be very useful.

Thanks,
Paddy